# What Windows 10 Control does the Alarms & Clock app use?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm making my first step in to creating Universal applications - does anyone know what the top bar control is in the Alarms and Clock app?

I noted that the middle section is a Pivot and it's switching between PivotItems - but when you change the top icons are highlighted based on the PivotItem

[image: Alarms and Clock]

Is it just a Grid with different buttons that are highlighted depending on the SelectedIndex of the Pivot control? Or is it a specific control that hasn't been documented yet?

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio 2015? Try to use UI debugging tools, The Live Visual Tree and you will see the exact type.

Comment: @user2250152 Does it work for core apps?

Comment: No it won't. But I'm sure it's just a custom template for the pivot header.

Comment: @TamásDeme I did actually get it working for Alarms and Clock but you can't view the source. It's a shame because I would love to use that the control layout. MS should be using standard controls for their apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just using a pivot with a custom header template.

This should provide some insight:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997788.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping it would be a standard control or style that can be used globally.

Comment: @Rohit Which control is used inside alarm section to select time?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Pivot sample in the [Windows Universal Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPivot) repository on Github. Scenario 3 contains the customized pivot control with the style template.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always debug any Win10 application by running visual studio and attaching the debugger to the process (app) you want to look into.

This will also give you all of the styles available and give you a better understanding of the layout. I demo'd this as part of the //BUILD tour earlier this year.